# Symfony and React - Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: reactjs, symfony, react-redux

I bought a theme who uses react and react redux. When I compile it there is no problem but if I include it on my symfony project I have this error:

```sh
⇒  yarn encore dev --watch
yarn run v1.13.0
$ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hyper_sf/node_modules/.bin/encore dev --watch
Running webpack ...


webpack is watching the files…

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                       20:22:10

 error  in ./assets/js/App.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected ";" (27:5)

  25 | configureFakeBackend();
  26 |
> 27 | type AppProps = {};
     |      ^
  28 |
  29 | /**
  30 |  * Main app component
    at parser.next (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)


 @ ./assets/js/index.js 3:0-24 9:36-39

 error  in ./assets/js/redux/store.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected "," (10:43)

   8 | const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];
   9 |
> 10 | export function configureStore(initialState: {}) {
     |                                            ^
  11 |     const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
  12 |
  13 |     const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));
    at parser.next (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)


 @ ./assets/js/index.js 6:0-47 8:9-23

Entrypoint app [big] = runtime.js vendors~app.js app.js
```

this is App.js

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Routes from './routes/Routes';

// setup fake backend
import { configureFakeBackend } from './helpers';

// Themes
import './assets/scss/Saas.scss';

// For Dark import Saas-Dark.scss
// import './assets/scss/Saas-Dark.scss';

// For Modern import Modern.scss
// import './assets/scss/Modern.scss';
// For modern dakr import Modern-Dark.scss
// import './assets/scss/Modern-Dark.scss';

// For Creative demo import Modern.scss
// import './assets/scss/Creative.scss';
// For Creative dark demo import Modern.scss
// import './assets/scss/Creative-Dark.scss';

// configure fake backend
configureFakeBackend();

type AppProps = {};

/**
 * Main app component
 */
class App extends Component<AppProps> {
    render() {
        return <Routes></Routes>;
    }
}

export default App;
```

and this is assets/js/redux/store.js

```
// @flow
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import reducers from './reducers';
import sagas from './sagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];

export function configureStore(initialState: {}) {
    const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

    const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));
    sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);
    return store;
}
```

I wonder what it might be missing in the packages.json?
I don't know where to find? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with this config of configureBabel() in my webpack.config.js:

```js
    // ...
    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })
    .configureBabel(function(babelConfig) {
        // presets
        babelConfig.presets.push('@babel/preset-flow');
        babelConfig.presets.push('@babel/preset-typescript');
        babelConfig.presets.push('@babel/preset-react');

        // plugins
        babelConfig.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not compiling typescript.

See here how to enable it in webpack encore: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/typescript.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my errors are still here, and if I add this line `.enableForkedTypeScriptTypesChecking()` in my webpack.config.js I have this error: ```  WARNING   Webpack Encore requires version ^4.0.0 of fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin, but your version (3.1.1) is too old. The related feature will probably *not* work correctly.
``` but I don't understand because in my package.json the version is `"symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.7",`

Comment: For this next question it might be better to search for how to upgrade individual packages for webpack encore.

Comment: I tried installing the right version with `npm i fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@^4.0.0` but the errors are still here. I wonder if we're looking in the right direction?